# How to capture the text from a UITextField swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am trying to simply capture the string typed into a UITextField in a GameController class that supports a MainViewController. My code below doesn't capture it into the wordAttempt string. Maybe its something to do with the textfield delegate which I am not sure how to set... Any help very much appreciated!

```
Class MainViewController: UIViewController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        controller = GameController()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 let gameView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))
        self.view.addSubview(gameView)
        controller.gameView = gameView
}
```

and then

```
class GameController: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

var gameView: UIView!
var writeText: UITextField!

self.writeText = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,200,50))
writeText.delegate = self    
writeText.becomeFirstResponder()
gameView.addSubView(writeText)

textFieldShouldReturn(writeText)
textFieldDidEndEditing(writeText)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    writeText.resignFirstResponder()
    textFieldDidEndEditing(writeText)
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.wordAttempt = writeText.text ?? ""
    writeText.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Is it currently printing: "wordAttempt is " ?

Comment: yes it prints wordAttempt is Optional("")

Comment: So the reason for this is that at no point do you have text in your text field.  What you could do is create a separate function that you call that then prints the writeText.text

Comment: i can type text into the simulator, but its not being captured either as above or in a separate function

Comment: question updated with working solution, thx to rkyr and SnarfSnarf

Answer (score 3):

If you want get informed anytime user enter some characters to your `UITextField` you should subscribe to it changes.

```
// inside your GameController
self.writeText = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,200,50))
writeText.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
writeText.becomeFirstResponder()
...
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
  let inputText = textField.text ?? ""
}
```

And you will get text that user type in `intpuText` variable. Because of optional type you should unwrap it before use. And `?? ""` means "if it nil put empty string to intputText, otherwise - text". This is why you see `Optional("")` when you output text.

If you need to know only when user stop typing consider [textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:) method of UITextFieldDelegate.

```
class GameController: NSObject, UITextFieldDeleage {
...
    self.writeText = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,200,50))
    writeText.delegate = self
    writeText.becomeFirstResponder()
...
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let inputText = textField.text ?? ""
  }
```

Comment: thx rkyr - I added the UITextFieldDelegate - big miss that! So thanks. And have got the textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method working. Do you know how to get the return button to call the textFieldDidEndEditing method as well? writeText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done doesn't seem to do it....

Comment: @richc take a look at reference to UITextFieldDelegate. it has method called [textFieldDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:). I think this is what you want. And when you use .returnKeyType you just specify how it should looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have it detect that the text has changed.  You could do this say with a separate button press.  Or you could use the textField delegate function `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to detect when the text has changed.  Note that you would have to set the textfield's delegate.